# How to trace web element though proper xpath or id or css selector

Tags: selenium-webdriver

please suggest how to locate the web element with help of xpath so that the chrome browser can except the location and proceed the test scenarios to be performed while automation testing and must not through an error of no element found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.